# is there any latest version of pyUIQ?

Tags: python, symbian

i have tried to install python for symbian uiq 3..i have tried signed and unsigned version,but both installation failed..anyone faced same problem?so,do you have any solution? i am using sony ericsson G900..

Comment: Does pyUIQ by any chance let you integrate it into your UIQ3 SDK so you could try your python code on the emulator? Any error there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though the pyUIQ version available is very old, you should be able to install it if you sign it properly. [Open Signed Online](https://www.symbiansigned.com/app/page/public/openSignedOnline.do) should do it.

Answer (score 1):

The latest release version of PyUIQ is 0.2, from YEARS ago, available [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyuiq/). No sources in the CVS repo on sourceforge, either... looks pretty much like a dead project to me:-(.  What do you need exactly?

Comment: i'm just trying to learn python on mobile phone..just to try what it can do ;-)

Comment: @programmerislam, if your phone is an S60 one, I think there's a better Nokia-supported version of Python for you.